# How do you modify JSON content in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have successfully intercepted an HTTP web request in an IIS7/ASP.NET application and using an [HttpModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) I have detected the content type is "application/json charset=UTF-8".

I used a [Proxy tool](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) to determine what the JSON content looks like.

I am using an HttpModule to intercept this web request and I would like to modify the JSON content.

My question is: how do you extract the JSON content into a JSON object, modify it, and update the original web request with my changes?

For example, suppose the JSON content looks like

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then what i want to do is:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "C H A N G E   1",
                    "SortAs": "C H A N G E  2",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using C# code to implement the HttpModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) you can do this:

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse("{'glossary':{'title':'example glossary','GlossDiv':{'title':'S','GlossList':{'GlossEntry':{'ID':'C H A N G E   1','SortAs':'C H A N G E  2','GlossTerm':'Standard Generalized Markup Language','Acronym':'SGML','Abbrev':'ISO 8879:1986','GlossDef':{'para':'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.','GlossSeeAlso':['AAA','BBB','CCC']},'GlossSee':'markup'}}}}}");

json.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.ID = 1234;
json.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.SortAs = "abcde";

string result = json.ToString();
```